# Modifying state & the correct way to update my reducer? (React / Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

I believe that I have been modifying my state for quite some time now. I wanted to do the following and was wondering why it did not work:

```
case "SAVE_DATA_TO_PERSON" :
        let newState = {...state, data: {start: action.payload.start, end: action.payload.end}};  
        return newState;
```

I am here creating a new object, take the old state, and add my new data.
While it does seem to make a difference, it does not keep the data for long. After firing other actions this is just gone. I wonder why?

This is how I used to do it, and it seems to work:

```
case "SAVE_DATA_TO_PERSON" :
        let newState = state;
        newState.audio = {start: action.payload.start, end: action.payload.end};

        return newState;
```

But here, it seems, I am modifying state.

I would just like to know whether my first solution is the correct one, and my second solution here is indeed modifying state.

Comment: Of course the second solution is modifying state directly--how would it *not* be?

Comment: I guess I thought I had copied the state into newState (as a new object), and was not working with a reference.

Comment: Nope, they refer to the same state object.

Answer (score 1):

In the second options you are modifying the state directly.

The reducer should changing state in a React-Redux application without mutate existing state.

> Immutability is a requirement of Redux because Redux represents your
>   application state as "frozen object snapshots". With these discrete
>   snapshots, you can save your state, or reverse state, and generally
>   have more "accounting" for all state changes. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958775/why-should-objects-in-redux-be-immutable).

You cloud consider using and immutable utility/library as [dot-prop-immutable](https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable) or [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Related article from redux docs:

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html